# Redshift | Serializable isolation violation on table | using lock

Tags: amazon-redshift

we have a stored procedure getting intermittent error called "Serializable isolation violation on table " on the update statement for the table, name incremental_table

I have read about the error. came to know one of the solution is to solve by using lock. I have tried it, but getting the same error. Below is how the code looks using lock. Why is the error coming again even using lock on the table. is anything I missed?

```
begin

 -- get the date from incremental_table

 -- do delta updates

 lock incremental_table;
 -- update incremental_table;

end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes two to tango.  This error has to do with the interaction of locks between 2 sessions on Redshift.  The error message gave you the transaction ids (xid) of the transactions in play for these sessions.  The code you have shown is for one of these transactions but you will need to find the other to truly understand what is going on.

Adding a lock statement "might" be part of a solution but just adding one to the terminated session is not likely to change anything.  Usually the later starting transaction will be terminated when the lock conflict occurs (but not always).  So it is likely that the other session is the one that needs a lock to prevent the second session from proceeding when the serialization error is possible.

You need a lock to hold of the second session or change the routines that are issuing these statements at the same time.  Option 2 is often better as there are likely more than one hazard possible and re-rationalizing processes (usually ETL flows) to perform actions on the database methodically will solve other, yet to be encountered, issues that won't be addressed by serially finding and fixing issues.